# Identify and plot datapoints surrounded by NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2, na

I am using `ggplot2` and `geom_line()` to make a lineplot of a large number of time series. The dataset has a high number of missing values, and I am generally happy that lines are not drawn across missing segments, as this would look awkard.

My problem is that single non-NA datapoints surrounded by NAs (or points at the beginning/end of the series with an NA on the other side) are not plotted. A potential solution would be adding `geom_point()` for all observations, but this increases my filesize tenfold, and makes the plot harder to read.

Thus, *I want to identify only those datapoints that do not get shown with `geom_line()` and add points only for those*. Is there a straightforward way to identify these points?

My data is currently in long format, and the following MWE can serve as an illustration. I want to identify rows 1 and 7 so that I can plot them:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(time=rep(1:5,2),country=rep(1:2,each=5),value=rnorm(10))
dat[c(2,6,8),3] <- NA
ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(time,value,group=country))

> dat
   time country      value
1     1       1 -0.6264538
2     2       1         NA
3     3       1 -0.8356286
4     4       1  1.5952808
5     5       1  0.3295078
6     1       2         NA
7     2       2  0.4874291
8     3       2         NA
9     4       2  0.5757814
10    5       2 -0.3053884
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` function to create a new column with values surrended with NA only. Then you can simply plot those points. For example:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

foo <-  data.frame(time =c(1:11), value = c(1 ,NA, 3, 4, 5, NA, 2, NA, 4, 5, NA))

# Perform sliding window processing
val <- c(NA, NA, foo$value, NA, NA) # Add NA at the ends of vector
val <- rollapply(val, width = 3, FUN = function(x){
    if (all(is.na(x) == c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))){
        return(x[2])
    } else {
        return(NA)
    }
})

foo$val_clean <- val[c(-1, -length(val))] # Remove first and last values

foo$val_clean

ggplot(foo) + geom_line(aes(time, value)) + geom_point(aes(time, val_clean))
```

[image: ggplot results]

Comment: I think this works if I change the part of the code where you drop a few values to: 
foo$val_clean <- val[-c(1,length(val))]
I will have a look at PoGibas answer too, and mark one of your responses as a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(time, value, group = country))
```

[image]

Comment: Not really, I would prefer geom_point at the isolated datapoints. Extending the lines will give me interpolation across some very long empty segments, which will not look good. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @notfound Hmm. I have to admit I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What are these "isolated datapoints"? Just to clarify: In above plot nothing is interpolated; we simply connect points with a straight line.

Comment: Isolated datapoints would be row 1 and 7 in my example. I want to add points to show that these observations exist, without having to draw a line to the next observation (which in my real data can be very far away).